# In WordPress run time display php code direct?

Tags: wordpress

**Below code in display my browser directly **

```
<?php
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    wp();

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}
```

This code is displayed on my screen please give me any solution

Comment: the code isnt in <?php tags  ?

Comment: This question is very elementary

Comment: yes on my browser this code direct display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your server is not executing any PHP and just serving the plain text files.

My recommendation would be to confirm that your server has started correctly and PHP is installed and working. Can you access phpMyAdmin, cPanel or run any php through terminal?

If it's installed locally, this might help: http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/software-and-web-apps/how-to-install-and-test-wordpress-on-a-local-server-50005338/.

Comment: But my other localhost projects run only one project having problem